# Can't add EventListener for custom button with FBSDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

To simplify my problem, I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK and Facebook Development Guide to make very simple file like that

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Get Facebook</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #fafafa">
        <div class="md-col-12" style="background-color: #FFF">
            <div class="md-col-1" id="face-img">
                <div id="status">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='myfb_login'>button</button>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow:hidden">
                    <img id='profileImage' src="">
                </div>
                <div id="friends"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
/*--Facebook util region--*/
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Initiate Facebook library
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '487932668044758',
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
        // the session
        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.4' // use version 2.2
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

};

// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        // fetchingUserInfo(receiveUserInfo, getAvatar);
        document.querySelector('#myfb_login').classList.add('hidden');
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
    }
}

var my_bnt = document.getElementById('myfb_login');
my_bnt.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click');       
});
```

Why my button (`#myfb_login`) cannot receives a click event ( I expect console print out "click" if button is clicked).

But if I disable the function `statusChangeCallback` in `FB.getLoginStatus` (by the way toggle comment), everything work as well as expected. And if I put a section of addEventListener inside a function `statusChangeCallback(response)`, everything is working as expected but I can't do it in my real project.

How could I understand what was happen and how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$(document).on('click', "#myfb_login", function() {
   alert("click");
});
```

Note: This requires jQuery. I only user jQuery so I can not provide a Pure Javascript solution.

Comment: Thank, it is working..but most of my code in real project using addEventListener so I have to understand what is happen and looking another way to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Is the javascript declared before the HTML? 
I mean, this:

```
var my_bnt = document.getElementById('myfb_login');
my_bnt.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click');       
});
```

is declared when the button is really present in the DOM?

Comment: No...never..I put javascript on the bottom of page and surely that all DOMs   are loaded

Comment: Let me figure out, if you click on the button "myfb_login" you haven't anything printed in the console right?

Comment: Ok, and what happen if you trigger the `my_btn.addEventListener('click',function()...` directly on the console. I mean, once the page is fully loaded.

Comment: In browser console...even a my_bnt is null with command:..
console.log('my_bnt', document.getElementById('my_bnt'));
VM179:2 my_bnt null

Comment: After page loaded aready..I type this command directly in console but it is null...:(...it's impossible..

Comment: It's strange, here I've pasted your code and I got the 'click' printed in the console.
[https://jsbin.com/fofuficofe/edit?html]

Comment: I see... but if used this code in your laptop...You may have same problem as mine... Dont understand why it is working in jsbin..

Comment: Could you try to fire the `console.log('click')` inside the `<button ... onclick="console.log('click')">button </button>` and see what happen?

Comment: it is working...but I can't follow this pattern because I have to use dynamic loading event

Comment: Actually.in jsbin say:
Navigated to https://jsbin.com/fofuficofe/edit?html,output
..
XHR finished loading: GET "https://jsbin.com/blog/all.json?Mon-Sep-14-2015".
To edit settings, type this string into the console: ol30b3n
d[ o_0 ]b
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes.
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: You can see this log if you open console log within your jsbin..:(.
It's mean no sdk.js of facebook is loaded at all

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm on Safari

Comment: It's really strange. I tested it both on safari and chrome and it works. 
I can't figure out what can be the problem! :(

Comment: Whai type of HTTP server are you using...Apache..???..You should test it with HTTP server to see problem..callback url must be provide...etc follows guideline of Facebook..

Comment: I've tried also in local so I don't think is something about the web server. Have you tried in FF?

Comment: No problem comes to me in case of local test.. Same result for all browser. I do a test with apache and also using small webserver of nodejs called serve https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve.. Problem is reproduced